# Agregar opcion mapa de google maps usando gmaps.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, map

Quisiera saber cómo podría agregarle una opción más al mapa de google maps 
https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/map_events.html

Por ejemplo, al lado de Satélite agregarle otra opción que me muestre otro mapa (que yo he personalizado). Viendo la doc veo que puede ser con eventos, pero no te especifican bien cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

En la propia página que enlazas, hay un apartado que se llama "[Map Types](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/map_types.html)" (en la sección *Utils*).

Si vas ahí podrás ver un ejemplo de cómo se puede añadir un nuevo botón (en su caso apuntando a un mapa de la misma localización pero de OpenStreetMaps):

```
map.addMapType("osm", {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
    return "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/" + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  name: "OpenStreetMap",
  maxZoom: 18
});
```

Como se explica en esa página (traducción mía):

> Puedes definir muchos tipos de mapa a partir de servicios externos de mapas. [...] Debes definir una función llamada `getTileUrl`, que devuelva una URL de la casilla dependiendo de las coordenadas del mapa.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas sencillo sería ir a la página donde tiene sus ejemplos
[ejemplos](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples.html)
Y una ves que lo elijas, clic derecho--> ver código fuente, ahí viene el cacho completo de código. Saludos!